# Does jquery interfere with php?

Tags: php, jquery, echo

I am trying to limit comments and replies to comments and display an error message once the limit is reached. I have successfully limited comments and comment replies, and successfully provided the error message when prompted ONLY for the comments, and not the comment replies.

The comment replies have a little bit of jquery working with them, so that's the only thing I can see that would be causing the message not to display. I have tried other methods then the one currently being used.

```
$valid = true;
$max_post_per_day = 5;
$max_reply_per_day = 5;

//THE REGULAR COMMENTS STRUCTURE THAT IS SHOWING THE ERROR MESSAGE PROPERLY

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `cysticBlogComments`
              WHERE `userID` = $auth->id
                AND `date` = CURDATE()";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
    $post_count = mysql_result($result, 0);
    $error_msgs_max_comment[] = "Whoops! You have reached the maximum amount of comments allowed for the day.";

    if($post_count >= $max_post_per_day)
    {
        $valid = false;
    }
    else
    {

    $query = "INSERT INTO `cysticBlogComments` 
                                    ( `blogID`,
                                      `userID`,
                                      `commentBody`,
                                      `status`,
                                      `date`,
                                      `time`
                                      ) VALUES (

                                      '" . $blogID ."',
                                      '" . $auth->id ."',
                                      '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BlogComment']) ."',
                                      'active',
                                      '" . date("Y-m-d") . "',
                                      '" . date("G:i:s") . "')";


    mysql_query($query, $connection);

}

<?php if(isset($_POST['commentBlogSubmit']) && $post_count >= $max_post_per_day ) {
                foreach($error_msgs_max_comment as $msg) { ?>
                <div id="error_x">
                <?php echo $msg; ?>
                </div>
                <?php }
                }?>

//THE REPLY COMMENT STRUCTURE THAT IS LIMITING BUY NOT DISPLAYING ERROR AND HAS JQUERY WITH IT

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `CysticBlogComments_replies`
                      WHERE `FromUserID` = $auth->id
                        AND `date` = CURDATE()";
            $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            $post_count = mysql_result($result, 0);
            $error_msgs_max_reply[] = "Whoops! You have reached the maximum amount of replies allowed for the day.";

            if($post_count >= $max_reply_per_day)
            {
                $valid = false;
                echo $error_msgs_max_reply;
            }
            else
            {

    $query = "INSERT INTO `CysticBlogComments_replies`
                                        ( `BlogCommentID`,
                                          `FromUserID`,
                                          `comment`,
                                          `status`,
                                          `date`,
                                          `time`
                                        ) VALUES (

                                        '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']) ."',
                                        '" . $auth->id ."',
                                        '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply'])."',
                                        'active',
                                        '" . date("Y-m-d") . "',
                                        '" . date("G:i:s") . "')";

    mysql_query($query, $connection);
}

<?php if(isset($_POST['sub_comment_reply']) && $post_count >= $max_reply_per_day ) {
                foreach($error_msgs_max_reply as $msg) { ?>
                <div id="error_x">
                <?php echo $msg; ?>
                </div>
                <?php }
                }?>

//THE JS FOR THE REPLIES

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {

            $.localScroll({ offset:{top:-40,left:0} });

            $("a.reply_link").click( function() {
                $("#"+$(this).attr('name')).fadeIn('slow');
            });

            $(".respond_nevermind a").click( function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var reply_box = document.getElementById($(this).attr('href'));
                $(reply_box).css('display','none');

                var reply_textarea = document.getElementById($(this).attr('href')+"_textarea");
                $(reply_textarea).val('');
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery cannot interfere with PHP, but you could affect the DOM with it and prevent something from showing up.  Check the code of the page you  are receiving in the browser to find out if your data is there.

Answer (score 5):

PHP operates on the server before JavaScript is ever executed so the two can't be interacting. The JavaScript *could* be having issues with the HTML produced by the PHP, though (in other words, there's just a JavaScript error) or the HTML itself may contain an error such as a missing closing `>` or quote.

Comment: I'm pretty new with j-query, did you happen to notice any errors?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not closing the `<?php` tag properly after the second `mysql_query()` call. You're opening a new `<?php` tag but I don't see the previous `<?php` tag being closed.