# if statement not triggering

Tags: php, if-statement

this is pretty much an updated version of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359260/does-jquery-interfere-with-php) I've already asked. I am pretty sure its the j-query I have is NOT interfering. For some reason my if statement in this case is not triggering as should. Long story short: I am able to limit the replies but can not get the error message to display.

Some of the if's are working, I will be sure to point out the one that is not.

Thanks in advance.

this IS working:

```
if(isset($_POST['sub_comment_reply'])) {
    if($_POST['reply'] == "" ) {
    $valid = false;
    $error_msgs_reply[] = "Whoops! You forgot to write your reply.";
    }else{

        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `CysticAnswers_replies`
                  WHERE `FromUserID` = $auth->id
                    AND `date` = CURDATE()";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
        $post_count = mysql_result($result, 0);
        $max_reply_per_day = 5;




        //Debugging lines
        echo "Query: {$query}<br>\n";
        echo "Post count for user id {$auth->id} is {$post_count}<br>\n";

        if($post_count >= $max_reply_per_day){
                $valid = false;
                $error_msgs_replies_max[] = "Whoops! You have reached your limit of answers for the day.";
        }
        else
        {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `CysticAnswers_replies`
                                            ( `QuestionCommentID`,
                                              `FromUserID`,
                                              `comment`,
                                              `status`,
                                              `date`,
                                              `time`
                                            ) VALUES (

                                            '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']) ."',
                                            '" . $auth->id ."',
                                            '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reply'])."',
                                            'active',
                                            '" . date("Y-m-d") . "',
                                            '" . date("G:i:s") . "')";

            mysql_query($query, $connection);



}
```

This is the portion of trying to trigger the error message and is NOT being triggered:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['sub_comment_reply']) && $post_count >= $max_reply_per_day ) {

    foreach($error_msgs_replies_max as $msg) { ?>
    <div id="error_x">
    <?php echo $msg; ?>
    </div>
    <?php }
?>

<?php } ?>
                <a name='reply_form_<?php echo $result['id']; ?>' style="clear:both"></a>
                <div id='reply_to_<?php echo $result['id']; ?>' class="respond_structure_future" <?php if(isset($_GET['reply_to']) && $_GET['reply_to'] == $result['id']) { echo 'style="display:block;"';}else{ echo 'style="display:none;"';} ?>>
                    <div class="respond_polaroid_future">
                        <a href="http://www.cysticlife.org/Profile.php?id=<?php echo $auth->id; ?>">
                            <img src="<?php echo $auth->img('mini'); ?>" />
                        </a>
                    </div>                              
                    <form name='comment_reply' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>' method='post'>
                        <div class="respond_body_future round_10px">
                            <div class="respond_arrow_future"></div>
                            <div class="respond_tail_future"></div>
                            <div class="respond_data_future">
                                <textarea id="reply_to_<?php echo $result['id']; ?>_textarea" name='reply'></textarea><br />
                                <input type='hidden' name='comment' value='<?php echo $result['id']; ?>' />
                                <div class="respond_nevermind">
                                    <a href="reply_to_<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">nevermind</a>
                                </div>
                                <input type='submit' class="submit" name='sub_comment_reply' value='Reply' />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
if (isset($error_msgs_replies_max)) foreach($error_msgs_replies_max as $msg) {
  // Do stuff
} else print 'No variable $error_msgs_replies_max';
```

?

Comment: that just makes the error message display when the page is loaded. I only want it to display when the submit button is pressed and the other criteria checks out

Comment: also it's notable to point out that when I add isset($_POST['sub_comment_rely']) to the your suggestion, or use it at ALL it completely kills anything from happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is also wrong you are using both `$error_msgs_replies_max` and `$error_msgs_reply` to catch errors .. please only use one eg `$error_msgs_reply`

you can also replace

```
   foreach($error_msgs_replies_max as $msg) { ?>
```

with

```
foreach ($error_msgs_reply as $msg)
```

Comment: He does have a post reply, look closer: <textarea id="reply_to_<?php echo $result['id']; ?>_textarea" name='reply'></textarea>